# Vauxhall zafira 2liter

Tags: manual-transmission

I have Vauxhall zafira 2 litre diesel and the other day I was sat on a hill at lights put the car in first gear and tried to set off I heard a clunk like something had dropped out of the car and then a grinding noice and the car would not move just rolled back so had to apply the handbrake. 
The car goes in all gears easy and clutch feels fine but when I put it in gear and release the clutch it’s just grinding and not stalling or anything.

I have notice that the front left drive shaft has snapped just wondering if that’s all that’s wrong with it any ideas thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have diagnosed a broken front left driveshaft, once that is fixed then it should work as normal from your description.